# Swift Quick/Nimble: Ambiguous use of expect

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing, quick-nimble

I'm new to Quick/Nimble, so I was trying out a simple Unit Test:

```
import Quick
import Nimble

class DarkSkyTests: QuickSpec {
    override func spec() {
        describe("simple test") {
            it("compares strings") {
                expect("hi").to(equal("hi"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Yet, on the expect line, I get the error:

> Ambiguous use of 'expect(_:file:line:)'

I don't understand why this is ambiguous. This is what it looks like in the Quick examples from what I can tell.

Comment: just to be sure did you recompile?

Answer (score 1):

I realized my problem was that I added source Swift files from Quick and Nimble to my Test target when I shouldn't have. Removing them from the target results in no more errors.